# SQL - Does Not Include The Specified Expression as an Aggregate Function

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm attempting to write a query that will calculate and list the student GPA's and then only displays the ones that are below the average GPA of all students. I have successfully gotten the query to output a table with the GPA's of each student, but I can not get it to only display those below the average.

The following is my current query:

```
    SELECT SC.StudentID, S.StdLastName, GPA
    FROM (SELECT SC.StudentID, S.StdLastName, ROUND(SUM(C.Credits * GV.GradeValue)/SUM(C.Credits), 2) AS GPA
         FROM ((Student_Classes AS SC INNER JOIN GradeValues AS GV ON SC.Grade = GV.Grade) 
         INNER JOIN Students AS S ON SC.StudentID = S.StudentID)
         INNER JOIN Classes as C ON SC.ClassID = C.ClassID
         GROUP BY SC.StudentID, S.StdLastName)
    GROUP BY SC.StudentID, S.StdLastName, GPA
    HAVING GPA < AVG(GPA)
    ORDER BY GPA;
```

When I do this, the error that appears is,

You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression GPA < AVG(GPA) as part of an aggregate function.

I have found multiple pages on a similar error on this site, but have still been unable to get it working. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you confirm what database you are using?  That does not appear to MySQL syntax, mainly due to the lack of derived table alias and the additional parentheses.  It looks like MS Access.

Comment: @bluefeet Yeah sorry. Put mySQL by mistake. This is in MS Access.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, I want to be sure you get the correct people looking at the question. :)

Comment: You've got a basic problem with this query: `group by GPA` will result in `AVG(GPA)` always being equal to `GPA`. I suspect the error is because you're trying to use an aggregate function on one of the grouping columns.

Comment: @Allan I'm not sure I understand. If I don't include GPA in the GROUP BY I get an error because anything in SELECT that isn't a function needs to be in the GROUP BY, no?

Comment: @MitulP91: That's correct. You can't use the average of `GPA` and the `GPA` from each line when you're getting them from the same result set. I'll try to illustrate the problem in an answer a little later.

Comment: @Allan Hmm. Alright. I'll keep messing with it, but I look forward to your take.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say `GROUP BY SC.StudentID, S.StdLastName, GPA`, you're telling the database to use those three columns to create groups of you data, then apply the aggregate function (in this case `AVG`) across each group. That means, as written, you're trying to filter each student's GPA against that student's average. Hopefully each student's average GPA is equal to their actual GPA...

In order to make this work, you need a second sub-query, which you can use to get the overall average GPA:

```
SELECT sc.studentid, s.stdlastname, gpa
FROM   (SELECT sc.studentid, 
               s.stdlastname, 
               ROUND(SUM(c.credits * gv.gradevalue) / SUM(c.credits), 2) AS gpa
        FROM      ((student_classes sc
              INNER JOIN gradevalues gv
                 ON sc.grade = gv.grade)
              INNER JOIN students s
                 ON sc.studentid = s.studentid)
        GROUP BY sc.studentid, s.stdlastname)
GROUP BY sc.studentid, s.stdlastname, gpa
WHERE gpa < (SELECT AVG(GPA) as avg_gpa 
               FROM (SELECT ROUND(SUM(c.credits * gv.gradevalue) / SUM(c.credits), 2) AS gpa
                     FROM  student_classes sc
                           INNER JOIN gradevalues gv
                                   ON sc.grade = gv.grade
                     GROUP BY sc.studentid))
ORDER BY gpa;
```

I'm not sure if this will solve your syntactical problem, but it should fix your logical problem.

Comment: Hmm. Yeah there are a few issues there, but I get the gist of it. I'll try it out. Thanks.

Comment: Brilliant. With a few small edits this worked. Much appreciated Allan.

Answer (score 0):

Does this get rid of the error? If it does, you can just select the sid, lname, and GPA FROM this

```
  SELECT SC.StudentID, S.StdLastName, GPA, avg(GPA) as avgGPA
FROM (SELECT SC.StudentID, S.StdLastName, ROUND(SUM(C.Credits * GV.GradeValue)/SUM(C.Credits), 2) AS GPA
     FROM ((Student_Classes AS SC INNER JOIN GradeValues AS GV ON SC.Grade = GV.Grade) 
     INNER JOIN Students AS S ON SC.StudentID = S.StudentID)
     INNER JOIN Classes as C ON SC.ClassID = C.ClassID
     GROUP BY SC.StudentID, S.StdLastName)
WHERE GPA < avg(GPA)
GROUP BY SC.StudentID, S.StdLastName, GPA
    ORDER BY GPA;
```

Comment: I tried that earlier. Says you can't have an aggregate function in the WHERE clause. Hence why I tried the HAVING.

Comment: regardless, I appreciate the time Scotch. Thanks.